# Opening handle response varies between IDE run and build run

Tags: c++

I used a method to find all pids of processes that have the same executable and I loop through them reading their memory.

```
HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, true, process_id);
```

and handle is always null due to error code 5 which is Access Denied when I run the built version but this never happens when I debug or Start without debugging in visual studio.

I am not sure why there is a permission difference between the manually ran file and the file visual studio runs (vs is in elevated mode when ran)

Comment: My guess would be, you run the IDE with admin privileges, and so the executable it starts also runs with admin privileges. But when you run it from, say, Explorer, it runs as regular non-admin users. See whether the behavior changes if you righ-click the EXE and choose "Run as Administrator".

Comment: `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is a lot of access. Is that really what you need? Maybe you can request less access that might not need an elevated account. Otherwise, you'll have to run the code from an account with appropriate privileges.

Comment: I may have forgotten to say but I run the program from explorer with admin privileges